# Deliver messages to multiple clients using different protocols (TCP, UDP...)

Tags: java, rest, networking, tcp, udp

I'm trying to create a small software component in Java which has the following workflow:

[image]

As you can see, it receives messages via a single TCP connection (being the client and listening to a stream). Each received message gets processed (means it is converted into another format and some information is added). Afterwards, the newly created message should be distributed among several receivers. The receivers can be grouped: some only unterstand plain TCP or UDP, some of them use a HTTP-REST interface.

Do you know some kind of pattern or best practice to realize this szenario?

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially describing an [Enterprise Service Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus). There are plenty of them available, from commercial software to lightweight open-source ones.